# How can I publish a Watch action for video, that clicking on the object will spawn a permissions dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-opengraph

Taking Viddy, metacafe, and many other, when I click on a Watch action' object (for a video of theirs), I am taken to the following link:
http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=125119214225766&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.viddy.com%2Fvideo%2Fb206f4a5-2256-4a6d-aee0-9a544ea4ef0f&response_type=code&display=page&auth_referral=1&fb_private_mode_enc=ASJTBOcbzLX2w7CG8O_y_nQlB4NgP5FKG1qo0WsqOoeipkrM_MCDSYUTx-7isbjlSiY

Clicking on that link, brings a facebook page (page as in web page, not Facebook Page) requesting permissions for the application (Viddy in this specific link). Only after providing the permissions (and sometimes by canceling as well) will I get redirected to the actual view page in the Viddy website for that video.

When I do the same with my application, the user gets redirected directly to my site, without being prompted for permissions.

I've compared everything I could think of, but I just can't get it to work the same.

What I've tried:

- Using my own custom action and object (og:type=myAppNamespace:myObjectType) with a myAppNamespace:myAction action
- Using the og:type=video:other and the video.watches action
- Adjusting the head prefix code for proper namespace of the Open Graph Protocol
- Any mixes between the option (the ones that can work)

If it wasn't clear by now - my app is a video app kinda like Viddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the recent [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) feature. I believe it's designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: But still, the metacafe and viddy links shows an auth dialog with the wording "Okay, watch video" whereas my app links shows an auth dialog with the wording "go to app".

Comment: @Doron It's a Facebook partner feature. Meaning, you cannot get this currently for your app unless you have a partnership with Facebook.

Comment: @TIMEX http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/371055139604673/?comment_id=371113026265551&offset=0&total_comments=4